# What is the friction coefficient of Object 1 and table top?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, string

Assume one box with a mass of 1 kg and acceleration of 5.41m/s² to the left. And another box mass of 2kg is hanging on a pulley with a weightless rope. What is the friction coefficient of Object 1 and the tabletop? given that moving to the left is the positive direction of object 1?

[image]